# Creating a table and bind it to an array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm pretty new at this programming thing...and I need to make a program which lists some customers and they need to be clickable so I can press a button to delete the selected item.

How do I create a table which will show all my objects from an array, and would make it easy to mark one item and click on a delete button?

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?  Or WPF?  I'm assuming you want a DataGrid or DataGridView and not a database table.

Comment: should i just make all the colums read only - and then make a method to delete the selected row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx), which you can bind to your data source (you might have to store the information in an ObservableCollection if it needs to be dynamic).  Then just have your button delete the selected row (make sure to disable the button if no rows are selected).

Comment: hmm.. i don't know anything about observablecollection.. might need to google that one

Answer (score 0):

Like an alternative to @Nick answer I can add ListView control in Details view mode. It's much lightweight then DataGrid, but also provides less functoonality. It's a metter of choice. If you don't need complicated stuff, but just: select row, delete row, may be search row, ListView could be pretty suitable option. But, I repeat, keep atention on your app requierements.

Regards.

Comment: That's true, a ListView is good for projects needing less functionality.